# oracle trigger to prevent insert operation

Tags: oracle11g

based on role number I am trying to prevent the insert operation. If role number>=103 it should deny.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ins_table
    BEFORE INSERT ON Tables 
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    userole number
    BEGIN
    SELECT role into userole FROM User_account where user_id = :new.user_id;
      IF (userole >= 103)
      THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Access denied');
      END IF;
    END;
```

The above trigger causes an compilation error

Comment: What is the compilation error ??

Comment: Put a semicolon(`;`) after `userole number`

Comment: thank you works now